# How to dynamically cast result-documents in mGo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I want to load and cast a structure from a mongoDB with a few different document types that can nest them-selfes. Let's say we have three different struct types, with one parent and two children

```
type Parent struct {
    ID bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty`
    Title string
    Description string
    NestedObjects []*Parent
}

type ChildA struct {
    Parent
    DateFrom time.Time
    DateTo time.Time
}    

type ChildB struct {
    Parent
    Options []string
}
```

The idea is to have a root-document holding other `ChildA` or `ChildB` documents. So an example document could look like this:

```
{
    "Title": "test event",
    "Description": "description goes here",
    "NestedObjects": [
        {
            "Title": "test event",
            "Description": "description goes here",
            "NestedObjects": [],
            "Options": ["foo", "bar"]
        }
    ],
    DateFrom: ISODate(...),
    DateTo: ISODate(...)
}
```

How can I now cast them dynamically into a struct (of the correct type)? The root-document is of the Type `ChildA` and the first nested document of the type `ChildB`. And the result I want is some kind of static type `[]Parent` which can be dynamically be casted to the sub types, somehow like this (pseudo-code)

```
for _ ele := range results {
    if ele typeof ChildA {
       ...
    }
    if ele typeof ChildB {
       ...
    }
}
```

(Just for some explaination: I want to build events like ToDo Lists, Polls, and some others which can contain each other. So like a event "Netflix&chill" can have a Poll & ToDos, example: ToDos: "Buy popcorn", "Decide which movie to watch -> [Poll: "Jurassic Park", "Inception", ...]".)

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `NestedObjects []*Parent` is a slice of `Parent`s, not children.

Secondly, it is not clear how you are going to discriminate your children and what you would expect in the result of, for example, `Collection.Find().One(?)`

It may worth to read [Unstructured MongoDB collections with mgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340031/unstructured-mongodb-collections-with-mgo) for good examples of how to use [bson.*](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson) types.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe a comparision to OOP/Java makes my problem a bit clearer: `Parent` would be a super-type, and `ChildA` and `ChildB` subtypes of `Parent`. In Java I could create a generic collection of `Parent` like `Collection<Parent> foo = new Collection<Parent>();`. So the static type is `Parent`, I could, how ever, add dynamic types like subtypes: `foo.add(new ChildA());`. So my question actually is: Is there a concept of static & dynamic types (from what I've learnt from digging further there is no such concept).

Comment: First of all go is not Java. Have a look at https://github.com/luciotato/golang-notes/blob/master/OOP.md  Secondly, mgo uses structures to marshal/unmarshal bson documents, read the docs how embedding may affect your models. Finally, design your structures and unittest them without  database to ensure it does what you expect.