# Go mgo get field type

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm creating an API in Go using MongoDB and mgo as storage engine.
I wrote sort of an abstraction for GET requests letting user filter the results by fields in query string parameters, but it only works for string fields.

I'm searching for a way to get a field's type with only field name, in order to cast parameter to correct type before searching in collection.
Here is the code:

```
func (db *DataBase) GetByFields(fields *map[string]interface{}, collection string) ([]DataModel, error) {
    var res []interface{}

    Debug("Getting " + collection + " by fields: ")
    for i, v := range *fields {
        Debug("=> " + i + " = " + v.(string))
        // Here would be the type checking
    }

    if limit, ok := (*fields)["limit"]; ok {
        limint, err := strconv.Atoi(limit.(string))
        if err != nil {...} // Err Handling
        delete(*fields, "limit")
        err = db.DB.C(collection).Find(fields).Limit(limint).All(&res)
        if err != nil {...} // Err Handling
    } else {
        err := db.DB.C(collection).Find(fields).All(&res)
        if err != nil {...} // Err Handling
    }

    resModel := ComputeModelSlice(res, collection)
    return resModel, nil
}
```

With mongodb I can check type with:

```
db.getCollection('CollectionName').findOne().field_name instanceof typeName
```

But I can't find a way to perform that with mgo.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about a way to get the type of the field *before* doing the query, but [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18346347/102371) approach is to simply query into an `bson.M` and then do type detection on the retrieved values:

```
var res bson.M
// ...
err = db.DB.C(collection).Find(fields).Limit(limint).All(&res)
// ...
for key, val := range res {
  switch val.(type) {
  case string:
    // handle
  case int:
    // handle
  // ...
  default:
    // handle
  }
}
```